# Twomon USB doesn't seem to work on high Sierra

Tags: high-sierra

it just doesn't connect it works fine on El Capitan but not on high sierra so I think it could be a security problem?

if its a software problem and it's just that twomon didn't update the software or something ill just have to get duet display or something that works on high sierra right?

computer: mac pro 5.1 High Sierra (Twomon USB app ver : 2.0.84)
iPad : ios 10 ipad 4 (Twomon USB app ver : V1.2.3)